# Downloading a library: "svn co ..." is blocking

Tags: svn

I want to download a library, on its web page, it is written:

```
If you want to download to the last committed version:
svn co svn://...
```

Then I run that command in a terminal, it started to copy files:

```
A   .../test
A   .../test/ctest1.c
A   .../test/ctest2.c
```

Then it is blocking: for 10 minutes nothing has changed.

Does anyone know what is happening? Could anyone help?

**Edit1:** If I want to cancel this checkout, I just need to close the terminal, and delete the local directory, is it correct?

Comment: It is either the server is down or a big file is being transmitted or anything else network-related, really.

Comment: Thanks for your comment... So if I want to cancel this checkout, I just need to close the terminal, and delete the local directory, is it correct?

Comment: Yes. The only thing SVN touches is your working directory and files and directories below. As for your original question, try searching for a sources snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

Check this SVN URL with **svn ls svn://...** (list svn url without checkout), then you can understand which file causes trouble, then **svn info svn://.../file** will bring you more information on this file.